# Changing placeholder content not working as expected

Tags: html, css

I have a placeholder in a page but am having trouble replacing the text with CSS. The input color, size, and font-style changes, but not the content? How can I replace the placeholder content?

```
input::placeholder {
  color: black;
  font-style: italic;
  content:"This isn't changing";
}
```

---

```
<input type="text" class="input-text" name="job_location" id="job_location" placeholder="e.g. &quot;London&quot;" value="" maxlength="">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell from looking at the docs you can not update the content through css for placeholder

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder

You could consider using js to update the placeholder.

```
document.getElementsByName('job_location')[0].placeholder='new text';
```